# How do I select multiple columns in my WHERE clause when selecting from a single table?

Tags: sql-server

I feel like I am missing something very simple here, I want to do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE 
WHERE COL1 > DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()));
```

It worked with 1 column but I want to select from multiple columns like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE 
WHERE COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4 > DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()));
```

I tried using `WHERE` COLUMN IN and it wasn't the right syntax and also I tried encompassing them in () and it didn't work either.

Comment: What logic do you want to achieve? All those columns are greater than the date, or at least one?

Comment: Use `apply` to avoid repeating the expression and use `and/or`

Comment: just if at least 1 column has a greater date, not a combination of all 4

Comment: If you want the COL1 and COL2, etc  to check against that date, you have to do each column individually.  So COL1 > Date AND COL2 > Date, etc

Comment: i tried doing that like this: `SELECT * FROM DATABASE.SCEHMA.TABLE
WHERE PRCS_DTE > DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()))
OR WHERE EFF_DTE > DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()))` but it says 'invalid syntax near where'

Comment: A `select` statement has *one* `where` clause - it would work without the additional `where`.

Comment: Side note: If `COL1`, `COL2`, ... are date/time values, should `>` be `>=`? Otherwise, you will be excluding potentially matching dates with 00:00:00 time values.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following

```
select * 
from database.schema.table
cross apply(select DateAdd(day, -2, Convert(Date, SysDateTime())))d(dt)
where col1 > dt or col2 > dt or col3 > dt or col4 > dt;
```

In SQL Server 2022 you could also do

```
where greatest(col1, col2, col3, col4) > DateAdd(day, -2, Convert(Date, SysDateTime())))
```

Comment: oh ok i think you figured out the right syntax, but now i am getting an error saying "COL2 doesnt exist" so i guess i have to apply what you wrote but include an IF COLUMN EXISTS statement

Comment: I would be curious to see an `if column exists` statement too, if your table schema is that volatile and you don't know what columns you have you have a bigger problem.

Comment: Nice answer, but for an `Any >` test, I think you need `greatest()` instead of `least()`.

Comment: @TN Doh yes that's what happens when you do too many things at once, edited thanks.